# systemd: After=<a service that's activated by a systemd path unit>

Tags: systemd, systemd-unit

### Context

I want `A.service` to be started only after `B.service` finishes starting up, and `B.service` is a unit that's activated by the corresponding systemd path unit: `B.path`. Relevant code snippets can be found below.

`A.service`:

```
[Unit]
After=B.service
```

`B.path`:

```
[Path]
PathExists=/some/path

[Install]
RequiredBy=A.service
```

### Problem

During bootup, I can see that `A.service` does activate `B.path`, and then `B.service` is activated after `/some/path` is there, but the problem is that `A.service` still starts before `B.service` finishes starting up. From checking the journald logs, the timeline looks like this:

- `T0`:

  - `A.service` is started (and then failed coz its setup depends on `B.service`)
  - `B.path` is started
- `T0` + `X` seconds:

  - `B.service` is started

`X` is somewhere between 3~6 depending on when the path comes into existence during bootup.

### Documentation

I checked the systemd documentation for `Before=, After=` ([link](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Before=)) and found this:

> If unit foo.service contains the setting Before=bar.service and both units are being started

This makes me wonder if it's because of the `both units are being started` bit. To be specific, `B.service` was only being started after `/some/path` is there, which can be `X` seconds after `A.service` was being started.

**However, I'm not sure if my understanding of the documentation is correct, or I am actually missing something else. Either way, any recommendation to write the unit files to achieve what I want is appreciated.** Thanks!

Comment: Why make B.path required by A.service then? Wouldn't it be much easier to want / require A.service with B.service? (And let whatever appropriate want / requires B.path, such as multi-user.target)

Answer (score 0):

A bit difficult to answer given that the actual unit files in question are omitted, but you seem to misunderstand what Before=/After= are meant to do;

The implication when using Before/After in unit files is that given a prioritization decision between two or more units, the Before/After conditions will determine the order in which actions are taken on the units.

In your case you have two services in which one service `A.service` is dependent on a second service `B.service`, however you have not specified that these two services have a dependency relationship, only the order in which they would execute **if** they had one.

With this being the case, it sounds like you want to also set `Requisite=`, `Requires=` or `Wants=` on `A.service` in reference to `B.service` such that `A.Service` looks as follows:

```
[Unit]
Requires=B.service
After=B.service
```

With this configuration, activation of the service `A.service` will necessitate activation of `B.service` and the `After=` directive will ensure that `A.service` will not begin execution of its `ExecStart=` directive(s) until after `B.service` has completed execution of its own `ExecStart=` directive(s)

`Requires=` and `Wants=` will not only check if listed units are already active, but will also activate them if they were not already

`Requisite=` will only check if a unit is running, if it is not, the unit it is defined in will immediately fail

`Before=` and `After=` only specify the order of activation for units when called simultaneously. Which is why you can have `A.service` activate before `B.service` in your current configuration, since they aren't currently being simultaneously activated, the ordering dependency is not applied.

It would be good coverage to also set `Before=A.service` on `B.service`

TLDR:
You need to define **both** `After=` as well as `Requires=`. You "need" `Requires=` to ensure that if `B.service` is not already running, it will be activated at the same time as when `A.service` is ran. You need `After=` to specify that when `A.service` and `B.service` have a simultaneous activation, that `A.service` will delay its execution until after `B.service` has executed.